# I can't find where I did wrong :(

Tags: python

I was working on project euler question 23 with python. For this question, I have to find sum of any numbers <28124 that cannot be made by sum of two abundant numbers. abundant numbers are numbers that are smaller then its own sum of proper divisors.

my apporach was : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/373f23098aeb5fea3b12fdc45142e8f7

```
from math import sqrt

def dSum(n): #find sum of proper divisors
    lst = set([])
    if n%2 == 0:
        step = 1
    else:
        step = 2
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n))+1, step):
        if n % i == 0:
            lst.add(i)
            lst.add(int(n/i))
    llst = list(lst)
    lst.remove(n)
    sum = 0
    for j in lst:
        sum += j
    return sum

#any numbers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.
#thus, only have to find abundant numbers up to 28124 / 2  = 14062

abnum = [] #list of abundant numbers
sum = 0 
can = set([])

for i in range(1,14062):
    if i < dSum(i):
        abnum.append(i)

for i in abnum:
    for j in abnum:
        can.add(i + j)

print (abnum)
print (can)

cannot = set(range(1,28124))
cannot = cannot - can
cannot = list(cannot)
cannot.sort ()

result = 0

print (cannot)

for i in cannot:
    result += i

print (result)
```

which gave me answer of 31531501, which is wrong.

I googled the answer and answer should be 4179871.

theres like 1 million difference between the answers, so it should mean that I'm removing numbers that cannot be written as sum of two abundant numbers. But when I re-read the code it looks fine logically...

Please save from this despair

Comment: This is not a SO question. Try your chance on Code Review and post your code.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Since the code has now been posted and it doesn't work, it is a SO question, albeit not a very well-written one.

Comment: Please explain what Euler question 23 is. A question should be as self-contained as possible,

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JohnColeman. I was just wondering is there any way to directly copy-paste the code without having to add 4 spaces manually for all lines?

Comment: You can highlight the code and then hit `ctrl+k` (or click the corresponding code icon at the top of the edit window).

Comment: I am less in despair, when I do not overwrite built in names like `sum`, when I do not name sets as `lst`, do remove local otherwise unused variables like `llst` and try to write in python more pythonic. Maybe lookup what `sum()` could do for you also ;-)

Comment: @AChampion, Oh I just realise how stupid I am. What was I thinking there. you are right.  But wouldn't the result itself get smaller if i add missing abundant numbers and find less numbers that cannot be made by sum of two abundant numbers? still there must be wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Wow, I just got the right answer after editing the bit @AChampion mentioned. But I still don't get how sum of numbers that Cannot be written by two abundant number increased when variation of abundant number increased ?!?!

Comment: NEVER MIND IM BLIND SORRY FOR BOTHERING EVERYONE I MISREAD THE DIGITS FOR THE ANSWER. I will go kill myself now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for some experience you really should look at comprehensions and leveraging the builtins (vs. hiding them):

You loops outside of `dSum()` (which can also be simplified) could look like:

```
import itertools as it

abnum = [i for i in range(1,28124) if i < dSum(i)]
can = {i+j for i, j in it.product(abnum, repeat=2)}

cannot = set(range(1,28124)) - can
print(sum(cannot)) # 4179871
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to improve your code.

Firstly, here's a more compact version of `dSum` that's fairly close to your code. Operators are generally faster than function calls, so I use `** .5` instead of calling `math.sqrt`. I use a conditional expression instead of an `if...else` block to compute the step size. I use the built-in `sum` function instead of a `for` loop to add up the divisors; also, I use integer subtraction to remove `n` from the total because that's more efficient than calling the `set.remove` method.

```
def dSum(n):
    lst = set()
    for i in range(1, int(n ** .5) + 1, 2 if n % 2 else 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            lst.add(i)
            lst.add(n // i)
    return sum(lst) - n
```

However, we don't really need to use a set here. We can just add the divisor pairs as we find them, if we're careful not to add any divisor twice.

```
def dSum(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, int(n ** .5) + 1, 2 if n % 2 else 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            j = n // i
            if i < j:
                total += i + j
            else:
                if i == j:
                    total += i
                break
    return total - n
```

This is slightly faster, and uses less RAM, at the expense of added code complexity. However, there's a more efficient approach to this problem.

Instead of finding the divisors (and hence the divisor sum) of each number individually, it's better to use a sieving approach that finds the divisors of all the numbers in the required range. Here's a simple example.

```
num = 28124

# Build a table of divisor sums.
table = [1] * num
for i in range(2, num):
    for j in range(2 * i, num, i):
        table[j] += i

# Collect abundant numbers
abnum = [i for i in range(2, num) if i < table[i]] 
print(len(abnum), abnum[0], abnum[-1])
```

**output**

```
6965 12 28122
```

If we need to find divisor sums for a very large `num` a good approach is to find the prime power factors of each number, since there's an efficient way to compute the sum of the divisors from the prime power factorization. However, for numbers this small the minor time saving doesn't warrant the extra code complexity. (But I can add some prime power sieve code if you're curious; for finding divisor sums for all numbers < 28124, the prime power sieve technique is about twice as fast as the above code).

AChampion's answer shows a very compact way to find the sum of the numbers that cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, it's a bit slow, mostly because it loops over all pairs of abundant numbers in `abnum`. Here's a faster way.

```
def main():
    num = 28124

    # Build a table of divisor sums. table[0] should be 0, but we ignore it.
    table = [1] * num
    for i in range(2, num):
        for j in range(2 * i, num, i):
            table[j] += i

    # Collect abundant numbers
    abnum = [i for i in range(2, num) if i < table[i]] 
    del table

    # Create a set for fast searching
    abset = set(abnum)
    print(len(abset), abnum[0], abnum[-1])

    total = 0
    for i in range(1, num):
        # Search for pairs of abundant numbers j <= d: j + d == i 
        for j in abnum:
            d = i - j
            if d < j:
                # No pairs were found
                total += i
                break
            if d in abset:
                break

    print(total)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

```
6965 12 28122
4179871
```

This code runs in around 2.7 seconds on my old 32bit single core 2GHz machine running Python 3.6.0. On Python 2, it's about 10% faster; I think that's because list comprehensions have less overhead in Python 2 (the run in the current scope rather than creating a new scope).